neko install undefined reference to `MPI_Comm_f2c' `ompi_mpi_byte'
I am trying to install neko v0.8.0... but when I enter "make",it halts
like this:
comm/comm_wrapper.o: In function neko_comm_wrapper_init: 
/WORK/thuscc24team13_work/neko-0.8.0/src/comm/comm_wrapper.c:16:
undefined reference to MPI_Comm_f2c

gs/bcknd/device/device_mpi.o: In function device_mpi_isend:
/WORK/thuscc24team13_work/neko-0.8.0/src/gs/bcknd/device/device_mpi.c:66:
undefined reference to ompi_mpi_byte

gs/bcknd/device/device_mpi.o: In function device_mpi_irecv:
/WORK/thuscc24team13_work/neko-0.8.0/src/gs/bcknd/device/device_mpi.c:78:
undefined reference to ompi_mpi_byte

I have successfully installed jsonfortran,and exported MPIFC,CC,FC,as
well as PKG_CONFIG with loaded modules as below:
$ echo $CC

mpiicc

$ echo $FC

mpiifort

$ echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH

/home/thuscc24team13/WORK/json-fortran/main/lib64/pkgconfig:

/apps/compilers/intel/oneapi/v2023.0.0.25537/vtune/2023.0.0/include/pkgconfig/lib64:
/apps/compilers/intel/oneapi/v2023.0.0.25537/vpl/2023.0.0/lib/pkgconfig:
/apps/compilers/intel/oneapi/v2023.0.0.25537/tbb/2021.8.0/env/../lib/pkgconfig:
/apps/compilers/intel/oneapi/v2023.0.0.25537/mpi/2021.8.0/lib/pkgconfig:
/apps/compilers/intel/oneapi/v2023.0.0.25537/mkl/2023.0.0/lib/pkgconfig:
/apps/compilers/intel/oneapi/v2023.0.0.25537/ippcp/2021.6.3/lib/pkgconfig:
/apps/compilers/intel/oneapi/v2023.0.0.25537/inspector/2023.0.0/include/pkgconfig/lib64:
/apps/compilers/intel/oneapi/v2023.0.0.25537/compiler/2023.0.0/lib/pkgconfig

$ module list

Currently Loaded Modulefiles:

1) compilers/intel/oneapi-2023/compiler/config    
2) compilers/intel/oneapi-2023/mkl/config    
3) compilers/intel/oneapi-2023/mpi/config   
4) tools/cmake/v3.25.2  
5) compilers/intel/oneapi-2023/config 
6) mpi/openmpi/v4.1.4 

I expect to solve the problem and install
successfully
More details:
see here

I can't post pictures,so the layout may be messy...

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

mpiicc and mpiifort are the wrappers for Intel MPI, but ompi_mpi_byte is an Open MPI symbol, so there is something fishy with this environment. Better try a fresh install.

You have loaded oneapi and openmpi modules at the same time. Don't load the openmpi module, if you want to built with the oneapi modules

I tried to install without openmpi module ,but failed.... the neko v0.8.0 itself is strange....

post the details if you need help.

Did you start with a completely fresh and clean build environment? Delete the source directory and unpack the source. With only oneAPI modules loaded, the source built without issues.
